# How to convert dashed word into camelcase

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to convert

```
my-dashed-word
```

into

```
myDashedWord
```

in Excel?

Comment: [Any attempts](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Please post whatever you've tried to solve this.

Comment: You want to remove every appearence of - in a given range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this small *UDF()*:

```
Public Function DashFixer(inpt As String) As String
   If inpt = "" Then
      DashFixer = ""
      Exit Function
   End If

   ary = Split(inpt, "-")
   For i = LBound(ary) + 1 To UBound(ary)
      ary(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(ary(i))
   Next i
   DashFixer = Join(ary, "")
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Other versions:

```
Public Function dCam(ByRef cel As String) As String

    dCam = Replace(StrConv(Replace(cel, "-", " "), vbProperCase), " ", "")  'MyDashedWord

    dCam = LCase(Left(dCam, 1)) & Right(dCam, Len(dCam) - 1)                'myDashedWord

End Function
```

---

```
=SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(A1),"-","") 'MyDashedWord

=LEFT(A1) & RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(A1),"-",""),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))-1) 'myDashedWord
```

Answer (score 2):

One more version.

[image: Dashed Word Extraction]

The formula in B2 is,

```
=LEFT(A2, FIND("-", A2&"- ")-1)&SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(MID(A2, FIND("-", A2&"- ")+1, 255)), "-", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine only VBA is going to be practical for you, but with a formula, copied across:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,FIND("-",A1),2),UPPER(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,1)))
```

Comment: Thanks - these are my rare attempts at formulas (I always jump to code) and your answer inspired me

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere near as efficient as I would have liked as there isn't a way to to a one shot replacement along the lines of

```
.Pattern = "\-([a-z)([a-z]+)"
Set objRegexMC = .Replace(strIn, UCase("$1") & "$2")
```

but as I did go there with a `RegExp` here it is.

```
Function StrCon1(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim objRegexMC As Object
Dim objRegexM As Object

Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "\-([a-z])([a-z]+)"
Set objRegexMC = .Execute(strIn)
For Each objRegexM In objRegexMC
    strIn = Replace(strIn, objRegexM,UCase$(objRegexM.submatches(0)) & objRegexM.submatches(1))
Next
End With

StrCon1 = strIn
End Function
```